# how to append json values to selection list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
[{"key":"0.75","value":"3/4","Default_Value":"0"}, 
 {"key":"0.875","value":"7/8","Default_Value":"1"},
"key":"1.75","value":"1 3/4","Default_Value":"0"}]
```

i have json array how to append this json has option to selection list

here is how i want to append

```
<option value="0.75">3/4</option>
<option value="0.875">7/8</option>
<option value="1.75">1 3/4</option>
```

and i need to select as default value if "Default_Value":"1" i am not getting how to iterate and get values and to display in key value pains in option and any help is highly appreciate.

```js
$("#p_combination").empty();
//supposing that your response object is something like :
var response=[{'dish_name':'3/4','dis-val':0.75},{'dish_name':'7/8','dis-val':0.875},{'dish_name':'1.75','dis-val':1.75}];
for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
 $("#p_combination").append("<option value='" + response[i]['dis-val'] + "'>" +response[i]['dish_name'] + "</option>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="p_combination[]" id="p_combination" multiple>
    <option value="0">Select</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $arrays=json_decode([{"key":"0.75","value":"3/4","Default_Value":"0"}, 
 {"key":"0.875","value":"7/8","Default_Value":"1"},
"key":"1.75","value":"1 3/4","Default_Value":"0"}]);
foreach($arrays as $array){
$select="";
if($array->Default_Value==1){
$select="selected='selected'";
}
echo '<option '.$select.' value="'.$array->value.'">'.$array->value.'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json is formatted wrong.  You're missing `{`.  I would use the `selected` attribute to set which is selected.  Aside from that, I just created a for loop that create each option and adds it to a `select`.

```js
var jData = [{"key":"0.75","value":"3/4","Default_Value":"0"}, 
 {"key":"0.875","value":"7/8","Default_Value":"1"},
 {"key":"1.75","value":"1 3/4","Default_Value":"0"}];

for (var i = 0, len = jData.length; i < len; i++) {
  var isSelected = jData[i].Default_Value == "1" ? 'selected="selected"' : "";
  $("select#buildSelect").append("<option " + isSelected + " value='" + jData[i].key + "'>" + jData[i].value + "</option>")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="buildSelect"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Values.
const values = [
  {value:"0.75", text:"3/4"}, 
  {value:"0.875", text:"7/8", isDefault: true},
  {value:"1.75", text:"1 3/4"}
]

// Select.
const select = $('#select')

// Append children using forEach + template literal.
values.forEach(({value, text, isDefault}) => select.append(`<option value=${value} ${isDefault && 'selected=true'}>${text}</option>`))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select"></select>
```